# Converting 12 hour clock time to 24 hour clock time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are lot of answers available on the S/O web, but i am experiencing an unusual error in the HackerRank python 3 shell with the below code which works fine in Jupyter notebook.

```
time1=input()
l=time1.split(':')
if 'PM' in l[2]:
    l[0]=int(l[0])+12
    l[2]=l[2].rstrip('PM')
elif 'AM' in l[2]:
    l[2]=l[2].rstrip('AM')
    if l[0]=='12':
        l[0]="0"
time2=''
for i in range(2):
    time2+=str(l[i])+':'
time2+=l[2]
print(time2)
```

This is the [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion/problem):

> Given a time in 12-hour AM/PM format, convert it to military (24-hour)
> time.
>
> Note:
>
> - 12:00:00AM on a 12-hour clock is 00:00:00 on a 24-hour clock.
> - 12:00:00PM on a 12-hour clock is 12:00:00 on a 24-hour clock.
>
> #### Example
>
> - s = '12:01:00PM'
>
>   Return '12:01:00'.
> - s = '12:01:00AM'
>
>   Return '00:01:00'.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the `timeConversion` function in the editor below. It should
> return a new string representing the input time in 24 hour format.
>
> `timeConversion` has the following parameter(s):
>
> - string s: a time in 12 hour format
>
> #### Returns
>
> - string: the time in 12 hour format
>
> #### Input Format
>
> A single string *s* that represents a time in 12-hour clock format
> (i.e.: hh:mm:ssAM or hh:mm:ssPM).
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - All input times are valid
>
> #### Sample Input 0
>
> ```
> 07:05:45PM
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output 0
>
> ```
> 19:05:45
> ```

I did try to run the same cases which gave errors on the H/R but worked alright on the J/P notebook.

P.S. I know this might be a super basic question I've come up with but please pardon me, I am still a newbie :)

Comment: `if l[0]=='12':` should probably assign "00"

Comment: Please post the full error with all available information.

Comment: Suggest learning about [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) and [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strptime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two issues:

- When the input has 12:00:00PM, your code returns an invalid result (24:00:00). It should in that case leave the 12 untouched.
- When the input has 12:00:00AM, your code returns the hour with only 1 digit, while 2 are required.

So change this:

```
l[0] = int(l[0]) + 12
```

to:

```
if l[0] != "12":
    l[0] = int(l[0]) + 12
```

And change this:

```
l[0] = "0"
```

to:

```
l[0] = "00"
```

With that it will work. Note that you are asked to write the body of the `timeConversion` function, so you should not have a hardcoded `time1=` in your code.

The final code could be like this:

```
def timeConversion(time1):
    h = time1[0:2]
    if time1[-2:] == "PM'":
        if h != "12":
            h = str(int(h) + 12)
    elif h == '12':
        h = "00"
    return h + time1[2:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def conv24(time):
    """
    Converts 12HR clock to 24HR clock
    time should be either 
    'hh:mm:ssAM' or 'hh:mm:ssPM'
    """

    l = time.split(':')
    if 'PM' in l[2]:
        v = int(l[0])
        if v < 12 and v > 0:
            v += 12
            l[0] = str(v)
        l[2] = l[2].strip('PM')
    elif 'AM' in l[2]:
        v = int(l[0])
        if v == 12:
            l[0] = '00'
        l[2] = l[2].strip('AM')
    res = ''
    for i in l:
        res += i + ":"
    return res.rstrip(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the logic from trincot; I just didn't split the string,

```
def timeConversion(s):
# Write your code here
 if s[-2]=='A':
    if s[0]=='1' and s[1]=='2':
        s = '00' + s[2:-2]
    else:
        s = s[:-2]
 elif s[-2]=='P':
    if s[0]=='1' and s[1]=='2':
        s = s[:-2]
    else:
        s=str(int(s[:2]) + 12) + s[2:-2]
 return s
```